# Registry key to tell if a server is a Read Only Domain Controller

Tags: domain-controller, windows-registry, windows

Is there a registry key I can check to tell if a server is a read only domain controller?

Comment: Can I rely on using  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DNS\Parameters\EnableRSOForRODC set to TRUE?

Answer (score 1):

I've now got a code snippet to check if the EnableRSOForRODC key exists, and if it does, returns it value.

```
1>NUL: 2>NUL: REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DNS\Parameters" /v "EnableRSOFor‌​RODC" || @Goto NoRODCExists
FOR /F "tokens=3 skip=1 " %%G IN ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DNS\Parameters" /v "EnableRSOFor‌​RODC"') DO (Echo Read Only Domain Controller? %%G.)
:NoRODCExists
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know EnableRSOForRODC works...

Comment: Thanks dfc, I'll move forward with checking that key. If I find a case where it doesn't work I'll update here.